# Extract month from date column

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a normal date column field. I need a calculated column displaying the month of this date.

How can I extract the month? I've already tried using this formula:

```
=TEXT([DATEFIELD],''MMM')
```

Answer (score 2):

This formula

=MONTH([DATEFIELD])

does the job

Or if you want the month name

=TEXT([DATEFIELD],'mmmm')

To add I see in your formula there is a typo

=TEXT([DATEFIELD],''MMM')

instead of 
=TEXT([DATEFIELD],'MMM')